# Wait for CSV file to open?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download and open a CSV file using VBA in Excel. When I step through using the debugger my code works fine but when I try to run it normally it won't work, it is trying to copy the info from the newly opened CSV file into the existing .xlsm file but it isn't finding anything. I have found ways of checking that the file is open but I need it to keep checking and once it does exist to continue with the code.

Here is how Im getting the file to download:

```
Sub getFile(address)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate address
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And then after this in the sub that calls getFile,

```
Do While Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Name <> "file.csv"
Loop
```

Ive tried a few variations that all work fine when taking it slow in the debugger but crashes otherwise. Does anyone know a way to have it keep checking and wait until the file is open? It requires the user to do something so what it to make sure that file.csv is open. Should I put my check in sub getFile  or keep it after it is called?

SOULTION:
Taking hnk's advice below I tried this and it worked perfectly:

```
Sub getFile(address)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate address
    Do While Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Name <> "file.csv"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Moved the check to before closing IE and added `DoEvents` to my loop.

Comment: you have to add "Waits" and look up readystate because when the code runs there is not enough time for the UI to catch up with the speed of code execution.

Comment: Great. so which approach worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually such behavior happens not because of the code logic but because of interrupts. Depending on the nature of your environment it could be one of two things

- some background refreshing process is getting executed sometime in between your code execution time causing some issues. e.g. in a financial services environment, your Bloomberg API could be doing its timely `BlpUpdate` event
- your code blocks up a large chunk of time and causes unexpected behavior because event which was triggered during your loop was blocked too long waiting for your code to complete on the main thread.

So you need to try the following two solutions, one of which should work

For the second problem, inside your

```
Do While Condition
' ... your code ...
Loop
```

add a line of code that checks for and clears any pending Event queues, making it...

```
Do While Condition
DoEvents     ' either put it at the start or at the end of your code
' ... your existing code ...
Loop
```

This will give the system some 'breathing space' to wrap up pending events. You'll need to experiment with the location of your `DoEvents` code.

For the first problem, you can try enclosing your entire loop within an `Event Protected` area of code, to ensure it finishes running before anything disturbs it.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

'your loop and other code comes here

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Once again, you might need a bit of trial and error to see how much of the code needs to be thrown into the Event-free zone before it works as expected.