# Slowing down vba to take into account network lag (outlook)

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a script to help me a little with resource planning. It's looking through a shared outlook inbox to find out when we receive the most emails, and so when we should avoid any breaks etc.

It seems to be working perfectly, but occasionally throws up a random error (type mismatch, call failed, operation failed etc). When I run the debugger from the error message it carries on as normal. It gets through around 800ish messages each time, between errors, and more if it's in a good mood.

All I can think is that sometimes the different subfolders take a moment to load. My code is below, is there anything that I can add to make it wait for a moment for messages to load from the server?

Thanks in advance.

Calling loop in the sub:

```
For Each msg In StartFolder.Items
    DoEvents
    msgData = ripData(msg)
    written = toExcel(msgData, strExcelFilePath)
Next
```

Functions defined below:

```
Function ripData(msg As Outlook.MailItem) As Variant
 Dim V() As Variant
 ReDim V(1 To 10)
 Dim minutes As Integer

 DoEvents

 V(1) = msg.Sender

 If InStr(1, msg.Sender.Address, "@", 1) > 1 Then
    V(2) = Mid(msg.Sender.Address, InStr(1, msg.Sender.Address, "@", 1))
 Else
    V(2) = "insight.com"
 End If

 V(3) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "short date")
 V(4) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "DDDD")
 V(5) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "dd")
 V(6) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "MMMM")
 V(7) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy")
 V(8) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm")
 V(9) = Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "hh")
 minutes = Split(Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm"), ":")(1)
 If minutes < 15 Then
     V(10) = 1
 ElseIf minutes < 30 Then
     V(10) = 2
 ElseIf minutes < 45 Then
     V(10) = 3
 Else
     V(10) = 4
 End If

 ripData = V
End  Function 

Function toExcel(data As Variant, excelFName As String) As Boolean
 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
 Dim spath As String, sFileName As String, fileWithoutExt As String, lrow As Long
 Dim i As Long
 Dim myWB As Object, oXLWs As Object

 sFileName = fso.GetFileName(excelFName)

 fileWithoutExt = sFileName


 Set myWB = FindOpenExcel(excelFName, fileWithoutExt, sFileName)

 Set oXLWs = myWB.Sheets("Raw Data")

 lrow = oXLWs.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

 '~~> Write to excel
 For i = 1 To UBound(data)
    oXLWs.Cells(lrow, i).Value = data(i)
 Next i

End Function
```

Comment: This question seems to describe a problem with a solution very similar to the one described here: (Hence it's a different problem but being caused by the same reason) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672024/wait-for-csv-file-to-open/24672988#24672988 and I've posted the solution below. If it's a repeat, please close it. Tks

Comment: Yes Martin, I believe the solution is more excel specific and can't be ported over to Outlook. I'll take out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Type mismatch means you are assuming that all items are MailItem object, but the Inbox folder can have other item typed ReportItem, MeetingItem, etc.). Do check the Class property ot make sure you have the expected object - it will be 43 (olMail) for the MailItem objects.

Secondly, you might be opening too many items - Exchange limits the number of simultaneously open objects. Plus "for each" loop keeps all collection elements referenced until the loop exits. Use the "for" loop

```
dim oItems
oItems = StartFolder.Items
dim I As Integer
dim msg As Object
For I = 1 to oItems.Count
    set msg = oItems.Item(I)
    if msg.Class = 43 Then
      msgData = ripData(msg)
      written = toExcel(msgData, strExcelFilePath)
    End If
    set msg = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, the type wasn't an issue, there are none of those types of items in the folders under consideration, and as mentioned the execution continues from the debugger if I just wait a moment.
As you suggest though I'll change over to a for loop - I'd not realised there was such a serious flaw in their implementation of `for each`

Comment: The good news is, that this allowed it to run through 1400 emails before dying. I'll see what other foreach loops might be killing it!

Answer (score 0):

If caching is not set on (account settings) for the shared folders you can get operation failed errors intermittently.